# To have colors in Vim LaTeX -files, like in Gvim

Tags: vim, colors, latex

The left-hand-side picture is in Gvim, while the right-hand-side one is in Vim.

[image]

Both Gvim and Vim uses the same files.

**How can you make `\item` red in Vim?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the same colorscheme in both vim and gvim?

If you set the colorscheme to the same they should look closer (provided the terminal supports the colours in the colorscheme). If they don't, you can change the colorscheme by editing `$VIMRUNTIME/colors/nameOfColorschemeFile`, or creating your own in your vim home directory.

You can set the colorscheme in vim/gvim with

```
:colorscheme nameOfColorscheme
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be happening because your terminal program only supports 16 colors, while gvim supports many colors.  Also, sometimes a colorscheme is designed only for gvim (or vice-versa). Best bet is to either change the theme yourself, or find another theme that has better support for both the gui and the terminal version.